# Better way to parse multiple files and create a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I want to:

1. Read a file into a dataframe
2. Do some data manipulation, etc.
3. Copy one column from the dataframe
4. Append that column to a second dataframe
5. Repeat 1-4 until all files are read

My implementation is:

```
all_data = [[]]  #list to store each set of values


for i in file_list:
    filepath =  path + i
    df=pd.read_csv(filepath,sep='\t',header=None,names=colsList)
    #various data manipulation, melt, etc, etc, etc.
    all_data.append(df['value'])

df_all = pd.DataFrame(all_data)  
df_all=df_all.T  #Transpose
df_all.set_axis(name_list, axis=1, inplace=True)  #fix the column names
```

How could this have been better implemented?

Problems:

- the data in the python list is transposed (appended by rows not columns)
- I couldn't find a way to append by columns or transpose the list (with python list or with pandas) that would work without an error :(

Thanks in advance...

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variable after reading file.  maybe you should transpose every df before adding to `all_data`. Or maybe you should check other methods to join/merge dataframes. DataFrame has `join()` to add columns.

Comment: if you would use dictionary `{"col1": df['value'], ...}` instead of `list` then `pd.DataFrame(all_data)` would create columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would keep data in `dictionary` then you would get columns.

But every column need uniq name - i.e. `col1`, `col2`, ect.

```
import pandas as pd

all_data = {}

all_data['col1'] = [1,2,3]
all_data['col2'] = [4,5,6]
all_data['col3'] = [7,8,9]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9
```

The same with `for`-loop

I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate files in memory - but you should use directly path to file.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

file_data = {
    'file1.csv': '1\t101\n2\t102\n3\t103',
    'file2.csv': '4\t201\n5\t202\n6\t202',
    'file3.csv': '7\t301\n8\t301\n9\t201',
}

file_list = [
    'file1.csv',
    'file2.csv',
    'file3.csv',
]

# ---

all_data = {}

for number, i in enumerate(file_list, 1):
    df = pd.read_csv( io.StringIO(file_data[i]), sep='\t', header=None, names=['value', 'other'] )
    all_data[f'col{number}'] = df['value']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

print(new_df)
```

---

You can also directly assign new column

```
new_df[f'column1'] = old_df['value']
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import io

file_data = {
    'file1.csv': '1\t101\n2\t102\n3\t103',
    'file2.csv': '4\t201\n5\t202\n6\t202',
    'file3.csv': '7\t301\n8\t301\n9\t201',
}

file_list = [
    'file1.csv',
    'file2.csv',
    'file3.csv',
]

# ---

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for number, i in enumerate(file_list, 1):
    df = pd.read_csv( io.StringIO(file_data[i]), sep='\t', header=None, names=['value', 'other'] )
    new_df[f'col{number}'] = df['value']

print(new_df)
```